# Cyclonedds: Can see topic when using ros2 topic list, but only can echo some of the topics over the wireless network

Tags: ros2

I have two PC in my setup. PC A [ROS Foxy] is connected to the router via Ethernet while PC B [ROS Humble] is connected to the router via WIFI.

When I run `ros2 topic list` on PC B, I can see all the topics from PC A however no all the topic can be echo with command `ros2 topic  echo`. For example I had IMU and 3D LiDAR running on PC A but I can only `ros2 topic echo /imu/data` on PC B. If I connect the PC B to the router via Ethernet and change the interface in  cycloneDDS.xml then I can echo the `/points` topic on PC B.

I found the following link saying about the issue was linked to the size of the message but I wrote a simple node to subscribe the topic and the callback is not triggered as well. Link: [Can see topic when using ros2 topic list, but can't echo it over the network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71574406/can-see-topic-when-using-ros2-topic-list-but-cant-echo-it-over-the-network)

Some people said it might due to different DDS middleware running on both PC but I have double checked the DDS implementation on both PC and both are running cycloneDDS. Link:
[Can see topic when using ros2 topic list, but can't echo it over the network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71574406/can-see-topic-when-using-ros2-topic-list-but-cant-echo-it-over-the-network)

**---- Update ----**
And yes the `CYCLONEDDS_URI` has been set correctly.

**PC_A**

```
PC_A@ubuntu:~$ cat cyclonedds_config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CycloneDDS xmlns="https://cdds.io/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://cdds.io/config https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/master/etc/cyclonedds.xsd">
    <Domain Id="any">
        <General>
            <DontRoute>false</DontRoute>
            <AllowMulticast>spdp</AllowMulticast>
            <NetworkInterfaceAddress>eth0</NetworkInterfaceAddress>
        </General>
        <Discovery>
            <ParticipantIndex>auto</ParticipantIndex>
            <MaxAutoParticipantIndex>100</MaxAutoParticipantIndex>
            <Peers>
                <Peer address="10.252.252.151"/>
            </Peers>
        </Discovery>
        <Internal>
            <MinimumSocketReceiveBufferSize>10MB</MinimumSocketReceiveBufferSize>
        </Internal>
        <Tracing>
            <Verbosity>config</Verbosity>
            <OutputFile>stdout</OutputFile>
        </Tracing>
    </Domain>
</CycloneDDS>
```

**PC_B**

```
PC_B@ubuntu:~$ cat cyclonedds_config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CycloneDDS xmlns="https://cdds.io/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://cdds.io/config https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/master/etc/cyclonedds.xsd">
    <Domain Id="any">
        <General>
            <Interfaces>
                <NetworkInterface name="wlp0s20f3" multicast="true" />
            </Interfaces>
            <AllowMulticast>true</AllowMulticast>
            <MaxMessageSize>65500B</MaxMessageSize>
        </General>
        <Discovery>
            <ParticipantIndex>auto</ParticipantIndex>
            <MaxAutoParticipantIndex>100</MaxAutoParticipantIndex>
            <Peers>
                <Peer Address="10.252.252.100"/>
            </Peers>
        </Discovery>
        <Internal>
            <SocketReceiveBufferSize min="10MB"/>
            <Watermarks>
                <WhcHigh>500kB</WhcHigh>
            </Watermarks>
        </Internal>
        <Tracing>
            <Verbosity>config</Verbosity>
            <OutputFile>stdout</OutputFile>
        </Tracing>
    </Domain>
</CycloneDDS>
```

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* Chun Jye Beh. Are you sure the topics are being published? Can you `rostopic echo` those messages from PC A?

Comment: Yes I can `ros2 topic echo /points `from PC A but no message appear when I echo from PC B [connect to the router via **WIFI**]. However if I establish the **Wired connection** to the router then I can `ros2 topic echo /points` on PC B.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* ! Could you please share your `cyclonedds` xml configurations for both PC, and make sure that the environment variable `CYCLONEDDS_URI` is correctly set on both PC ? (i.e. points toward the .xml configuration file)

Answer (score 2):

As I cannot comment, I'll post it as an answer. I just want to suggest trying to set `<Domain Id="any">` to, for example, `<Domain Id="1">` for both of them, as this is, as far as I understand, how the `ROS_MASTER` setup is done in ROS2. Let me know if this does anything.

Comment: That is the common mistake but for my case is a bit special. I can echo some of the topics but no all of them. For example I can echo IMU data but no pointcloud data. However, when I connect the PC_B to the router via LAN cable, then I am able to echo the pointcloud data.

Comment: There is a reported [reliability issue for sending  large messages over lossy links like wifi](https://discourse.ros.org/t/investigation-into-alternative-middleware-solutions/32642/15). How large are your point clouds? A relevant test might be to publish small point clouds (e.g. a few points) and see if they arrive, and gradually try larger.

Comment: I can add additional comments about this from new experience. In our lab we noticed that some data won't go through if the computers are not on the same subnet. One of the computers was on 192.X... and the other on 10.X... and specifically pointcloud data was getting stuck. When the two PCs were set on the same subnet (10.X...), the data went through!